# Make list with while loop ? python3

Tags: python

I'm trying to make  list  contain (even numbers) with using while loop :

```
a=0
while a<8:
    a=a+2
    print(a,end=' ')
    t=list(a)
    print (t)
```

and how do I can make a code to division the numbers from the first list into two list: one for(even numbers) and the other for (odd numbers) ?

Answer (score 1):

You can just create a `list` directly from each variable

```
>>> a = list(a)
>>> a
[1, 2, 3]

>>> b = list(b)
>>> b
['C', 'i', 't', 'y']
```

To make a list of even numbers using a `while` loop, you can do something like this

```
a = 0
t = []
while a < 8:
    t.append(a)
    a += 2

>>> print(t)
[0, 2, 4, 6]
```

Note that the above is just for learning purposes, this can be done using Python's `range` function more easily

```
>>> list(range(0, 8, 2))   # Evens
[0, 2, 4, 6]

>>> list(range(1, 8, 2))   # Odds
[1, 3, 5, 7]
```

Comment: Please either edit your question to include the code and what is not working about it, or post a new question if it is separate than the one you initially asked.

Comment: a=(1,2,3,4,5,6)
I'm trying to make two lists the first contain the even numbers and the other one contain the odd numbers.
I used while loop and when I put (a=list(a))  it doesn't work : 
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: Post your actual while loop, not just that line

Comment: All of the formatting of your code is lost in the comment section. As I said before, please **edit your post** or **post a new question**. It is very difficult to parse your code without any formatting or indentation

Answer (score 1):

Use `list` to convert.

```
In [1]: a=(1,2,3)

In [2]: list(a)
Out[2]: [1, 2, 3]

In [3]: b=('City')

In [4]: list(b)
Out[4]: ['C', 'i', 't', 'y']
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is my answer to your question:

```
List = []
ListEven = []
ListOdd = []
Count = 0
while(Count < 11):
    print(Count, end = ' ')
    List.append(Count)
    if(Count % 2 == 0):
        ListEven.append(Count)
    elif(Count % 2 != 0):
        ListOdd.append(Count)
    Count += 1
print("\n""This is the main list:")
print(List)
print("This is the even list:")
print(ListEven)
print("This is the odd list:")
print(ListOdd)
```

I fixed the Count from `Count += 2` to `Count += 1` because you asked for a `list of odds`. The code you had would `only produce even numbers`. I hope this helped answer your question. :)

Comment: -.- How is my answer not good enough the sense that someone thought it deserved a down arrow, please explain!

Comment: Your answer does not address the question any better than any of the existing answers, includes extraneous and unexplained code that is not needed to answer the question, does not follow standard python coding style, and was added over a year after the original question was both asked and correctly answered.